# Multiline header background hover

Tags: css

I have a hover animation on the headers where an underline transforms into the height of the header. Using `:before` with `height` set to `3px` and then changed to `100%`.

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: crimson;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.25s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.25s;
  -o-transition: height 0.25s;
  transition: height 0.25s;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1:hover:before {
  background: crimson;
  height: 100%;
}
```

It works great however the problem is when the header has multiple lines the effect is more of a 'block' background rather than 'wrapped' around the header. I tried to do this by adding a `span`. The underline is solvable but I still cannot figure out a way to have the same effect with changing the `height` on the `span` as I have done with the `:before`.

I'm not sure if this is possible in any way.

Example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/semajtwin/pen/htnLy?editors=110

**Update**

As suggested by coma adding `span`'s solves the issue. I've added some jQuery to add the `span`'s to make it a bit dynamic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get h1
  var h1 = $('h1');
  // split by spaces
  var h1_text = h1.html().split(' ');

  var h1_text_updated = '';
  // for each word
  for (var i=0; i<h1_text.length; i++) {
    //insert span
    var text = h1_text[i];

    // if not last word, add space
    h1_text_updated += (i < h1_text.length-1) ? '<span>' + text + '&nbsp;</span>' : '<span>' + text + '</span>';
  }

  h1.html(h1_text_updated);
});
```

I don't think it looks that great having to add `&nbsp;` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping every word in a `span` to get the correct height:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/19vz9g2y/

```
<h1>
   <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
</h1>
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/19vz9g2y/1/

```
var apply = function (elements, method) {

    Array
        .prototype
        .forEach
        .call(elements, method);
};

apply(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'), function (h1) {

    h1.innerHTML = h1.innerText.replace(/\S+/g, function (word) {

        return '<span>' + word + '</span>';
    });

    var a = -1;
    var lines = [];

    apply(h1.children, function (span) {

        if (span.offsetTop > a) {

            a = span.offsetTop;
            lines.push(span.innerText);

        } else {

            lines[lines.length - 1] += ' ' + span.innerText;
        }
    });

    h1.innerHTML = '<span>' + lines.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: That works fine but the headers will vary from single to multi line and it's not quite dynamic. This method does cause a bit of a problem in single line headers due to white spaces...unless you add `&nbsp;` in `span`'s but the code doesn't look nice at all. On the other hand, I still can't find a better solution yet.

Comment: I've extended your solution by using javascript to add the `span`'s, that kind of makes it a bit dynamic

Comment: @j.grima, mine does not add extra white spaces.